# Unable to fetch Parent data from Child

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, mapping

I'm trying to see whether a `Cab` is assigned to any `Employee` so I can fetch that `Employee` Id and simply to set cab as `null`, but `@OneToMany` mapping, simply returning a list of Employees & by this I'm not getting any method like a `cab.getEmp()` to fetch employee details

**Employee.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    
     @Id
     private Integer id;
     private String username;
     private String password;
     private String role;
     private String dropLocation;
    
     @ManyToOne(
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
         fetch = FetchType.EAGER
     )
    
     @JoinColumn(
         name = "empCab",
         referencedColumnName = "cabId"
     )

     public Cab cab;
}
```

**Cab.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cab")
public class Cab {
    
     @Id
     private Integer cabId;
     private Integer cabNumber;
     private String cabShift;
        
     @OneToMany(
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
         fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
         mappedBy= "cab"
     )

     private List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("deleteCab")
public ModelAndView deleteCab(@RequestParam("id") Integer id, ModelAndView mvc){
         Cab cab = cabRepo.findById(id).orElse(null);
         if(cab!=null){
             List<Employee> emp =  cab.getEmp();
             if(!cab.getEmp().isEmpty()){
                 //e1.setCab(null);
                 //empRepo.save(e1);
                 mvc.addObject("msg", "Cab deleted & an employee cab detail also got changed");
                 mvc.setViewName(NOTHING_JSP);
             } else {
                 cabRepo.deleteById(id);
                 mvc.addObject("msg", "Cab removed from the database");
                 mvc.setViewName(NOTHING_JSP);
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: Can you debug your code?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I'm getting all employee data in cab.getEmp() but since it is returning a list how can I now set all employee cab to null to remove a cab

Comment: Try `cab.getEmp().getCabId()` instead of `cab.getEmp()`

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I can directly getting getCabId() but I want the Id of the employee who are riding in the cab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `Cab` is perent class and `Employee` is child class and your goal is to remove the child class dependency with parent class. For that, You have to extract the `Employee` from `Cab` and remove the relationship with `Cab` using `employee.setCab(null)`.

```
@GetMapping("/deleteCab")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView deleteCab(@RequestParam("id") Integer id, ModelAndView mvc){
    Cab cab = cabRepo.findById(id).orElse(null);
    if(cab != null){
         // Extract employee from cab
         for(Employee emp: cab.getEmp())
         {
            // Remove the relationship with cab
            emp.setCab(null);
         }
         cabRepo.save(cab);
         mvc.addObject("msg", "Cab deleted & an employee cab detail also got changed");
         mvc.setViewName(NOTHING_JSP);
    } else {
         cabRepo.deleteById(id);
         mvc.addObject("msg", "Cab removed from the database");
         mvc.setViewName(NOTHING_JSP);
    }
    return mvc;
}
```